# Get a particular input element from a particular form

Tags: c#, mshtml, dom, ihtmldocument

Like the statement,

```
string value = document.forms["sap.client.SsrClient.form"].elements["sapwdssr..requestCounter"].value;
```

in javascript, is there a corresponding statement to get the value of a particular input element within a particular form in C#?

I can do so by using HTMLDocument and mshtml interface. But that is a rather cumbersome process so if any direct method or property exists it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are asking to *parse* HTML, rather than attempting to do some form of runtime manipulation of a rendered web page, correct?

If that's the case, I highly suggest you look into the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), which we have used very successfully to parse HTML as if it were XML. You could do your stuff with a simple XPath query.

Comment: No I don't need to parse the HTML. Rather I need to use that particular value of the input element on the page.

Comment: @arunondeck: Do you have an embedded browser in your application, or is this executing in, say, Chrome?

Comment: Actually its an addon for IE. I'm using mshtml to get the HTML source.

Comment: The HTML source? So you're not actually hoping to walk the DOM? Sounds like HTML Agility Pack may be what you need after all.

Comment: What would I need to do in order to walk the DOM?

Comment: @arunondeck: if you're doing it in the context of an IE addon, then you absolutely have to use [MSHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317(VS.85).aspx). TreeWalker and a complex loop should do the trick.